# why IF condition using && is not working in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have problem in if condition using && in javascript. The conditional statements aren't working, and I have no idea why. Here the code:

```
<script type = 'text/javascript'>
function computeLoan(){
var leasing = document.getElementById('leasing').value; // the data are taken from select option in HTML
var tenor = parseInt(document.getElementById('tenor').value); // the data are taken from select option in HTML
var ten = tenor/2;
var otr = document.getElementById('otr').value;
var dp = document.getElementById('dp').value;
// var total = 0;

if ((leasing = "PT. Adira Dinamika Multi Finance, Tbk") && (tenor == "24")) 
{
    interest = 0.039;
}    
if ((leasing = "PT. Adira Dinamika Multi Finance, Tbk") && (tenor == "36")) 
{
    interest = 0.042;
}
if ((leasing == "PT. Wahana Ottomitra Multiartha (WOM)") && (tenor == '24')) 
{
    interest = 0.036;
}
if ((leasing == "PT. Wahana Ottomitra Multiartha (WOM)") && (tenor == '36')) 
{
    interest = 0.041;
}
if ((leasing == "PT. Summit Oto Finance") && (tenor == '24')) {
    interest = 0.0355;
}
if ((leasing == "PT. Summit Oto Finance") && (tenor == '36')) {
    interest = 0.04;
}

total = (((otr - dp) * interest * ten) + (otr - dp))/tenor;
$("#monthly").val(total);

}
</script>
```

Comment: `=` is not the same as `==`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the first if statement:

```
if ((leasing = "PT. Adira Dinamika Multi Finance, Tbk") && (tenor == "24"))
```

Where it says

```
leasing = "PT. Adira Dinamika Multi Finance, Tbk"
```

You're using the wrong = sign - it should be ==. = is the variable assignment operator, == is the equivalence operator. Fix the if statement so it looks like this:

```
if ((leasing == "PT. Adira Dinamika Multi Finance, Tbk") && (tenor == "24"))
```

And your code will work.

Comment: I already changed it into == , but it doesn't work. the value of total is not appear